# t1-fontenc and overfull boxes

Tags: fonts

I understand that T1-fontencoding shall help with hyphenation of words with accented letters (I am german) and it does. But on the other hand it can produce overfull boxes of text (and maths) without any german influence, overfull boxes which do not occur **without** using t1-fontenc and also not in plain TeX. A mwe is enclosed which I ran twice, **with** t1-fontenc and **without**.

I am a bit astonished as I thought simple tex-code, especially math-code should always produce the same output.

Is this behaviour correct, or does it show any inconsistencies in my miktex-istallation?

If it is correct I wonder whether I should use T1-fontenc, as hyphenation-problems with accented letters can be handled by including optional hyphens, while an overfull box occurring in math-code is not so easy to avoid.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %wichtig für Trennung von worten mit umlauten!
                             %Nicht immer optimal, lohnt sich vielleicht nicht
\textwidth=159.92mm
\overfullrule4pt
\begin{document}
Man definiert rekursiv die mehrfache Verknupfung in Gruppen, und zwar fur
$n\in N$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in G$:
\end{document}
```

Output **with** t1-fontenc:

[image: dvi-output without t1-fontenc]

Output **without** t1-fontenc:

[image: dvi-output without usind t1-fontenc]

Comment: The typesetting with OT1 is rather poor anyway. The font metrics for Computer Modern (OT1) and European Modern (T1) are slightly different. If you add `\usepackage{lmodern}` you get identical output in both cases: poor, as I said.

Comment: Thanks for this fast replay. I thought that the font metrics for  cm and ec-fonts were identical. If this isn't the case, all is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use T1. You are not more or less likely to get overfull box problems, with either encoding, it is just that as the metrics are different and (in general but not this example) all linebreaking will be different in a paragraph if the hyphenation changes.  So sometimes you will get problem cases in one but not the other setting.

In the example that you show it is just a difficult line to set, neither looks good, the T1 version is far too cramped (and still overfull) and the OT1 version is very loose and spaced out. I'd try to change the words somewhere or if that is really not possible, use T1 and `\sloppy` (just for that paragraph)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer concerning using of T1 and in particular to your hint that both linebreakings have disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get better line wrapping and word spacing, two things you can do are: load the correct hyphenation patterns for your language with `babel`, and load `microtype` to enable font expansion.  (The latter works in LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX, but not XeLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %wichtig für Trennung von worten mit umlauten!
                            %Nicht immer optimal, lohnt sich vielleicht nicht
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\textwidth=159.92mm
\overfullrule4pt
\begin{document}
Man definiert rekursiv die mehrfache Verknupfung in Gruppen, und zwar fur
$n\in N$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in G$:
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

These techniques will still work if you load a different font, or even run LuaLaTeX and load `fontspec` (or `unicode-math`) to use Unicode.  If that is an option for you, I recommend it over legacy 8-bit fonts.

This example comes out essentially identical to your first sample, so if it’s unattractive to you, consider changing the layout, such as by using display math.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My interest was not to get a better linebreaking but to understand why there are differences, as I (wrongly) thought that there shouldn't be one. The use of babel was avoided in the MWE to show that accented letters did not matter here (therefore the wrong german word fur instead of für).